# How to multiply values of matching keys together?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
x = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
y = {"b": 4, "c": 5, "d": 6}
for key in x:
    if key in y:
        a = (x[key])
        b = (y[key])
```

This returns `a` as `2 3` and `b` as `4 5`. What i'm trying to do is multiply the matching key values together and then add those values together. I am not quite sure how to do this. If you guys could help me out that would be great. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Why don't you tell us your expected output for the example you give?

Comment: i want the final value i get to be (2*4)+(3*5) =23

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this would be to just keep a running total, e.g.:

```
total = 0
for key in x:
    if key in y:
        a = x[key]
        b = y[key]
        total += a*b
print(total) # 23
```

But python has powerful comprehensions/generators that can simplify this to:

```
>>> sum(x[key]*y[key] for key in x if key in y)
23
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) with a generator:

```
x = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
y = {"b": 4, "c": 5, "d": 6}

sum(x[k] * y[k] for k in set(x) & set(y))
# 23
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!